# Display pthreads priority

Tags: linux, pthreads

I have a process (testsuit). In this process I use two pthreads ( T1 and T2 ).

Is there a possibility to display information about this threads on the shell ( especially the priority)?

If I use `top -H` I can see noting.

`ps axms` show me this

```
  UID   PID   PENDING   BLOCKED   IGNORED    CAUGHT STAT TTY        TIME COMMAND
    0     1  00000000         -         -         - -    ?          0:00 init [3

    .
    .
    .

    0  1063  00000000         -         -         - -    ttyS0      0:00 ./tests
    0     -  00000000  00000000  00000000 <80000000 Sl   -          0:00 -
    0     -  00000000  00000000  00000000 <80000000 Rl   -          0:00 -
    0     -  00000000  00000000  00000000 <80000000 Rl   -          0:00 -
```

I think there is no indication of Priority.

That are the things I found out. ( feel free to edit it )

- UID     =
- PID     = process ID
- PENDING =
- BLOCKED =
- IGNORED =
- CAUGHT  =
- STAT    = process state
- TTY     = Terminal associated with the process
- TIME    = cumulated CPU time
- COMMAND = executable name

NOTE:

I use Linux 2.4.36 without gui

Comment: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21253653/individual-thread-priority-checking-using-command-line-in-linux). There are some good working answers there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a programmatic way.

> ```
>    pthread_getschedparam(pthread_t thread, int *policy,
>                          struct sched_param *param);
> ```

This function gives ya the scheduling parameters, in the struct sched_param you can find the scheduling priority as an integer.
Use that and print it to the screen.

For a better explanation, please check this man page:
http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_setschedparam.3.html

Answer (score 0):

You could check /proc/PID/task directory. Each thread under given PID is creating directory with quite many information there.

Comment: I don't have such a dir (PID is missing) I use Linux 2.4.36

Comment: I don't know if you understand correctly. PID is number of your process. You could easily find it by typing ps a | grep your_process_name. This should show you some value (e.g 1234). Then you can find something like /proc/1234/task/

Comment: Oh, it was a misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

If `top` is running use the command `f` to display the list of possible column/fields. There select the "Nice value" by pressing `i`.

Verbatim from `man top`:

> NI  --  Nice value
>
> The nice value of the task. A negative nice value
>   means higher priority, whereas a positive nice value means lower
>   priority. Zero in this field simply means priority will not be
>   adjusted in determining  a  task's  dispatchability.

Answer (score 0):

with top -H you can see number of threads look picture [top with -H option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S825I.jpg)

There is a lot of information, it's easier to run with top -H -p