# Individual thread priority checking using command line in linux

Tags: linux, multithreading, pthreads, embedded-linux, thread-priority

I can see number of threads used in application by going to /proc/$(pidof task)/ and giving

> cat status.

Is there any way to check individual thread priority in linux using commands?

Regards,
Learner

Answer (score 4):

Run ps with`-m -l`. It will list all the thread and priority with respect to particular PID

```
ps -m -l [PID]
```

Example:

```
PC@PCuser:~$ ps -m -l 10070

F S   UID   PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  TTY        TIME CMD
0 -  1000 10070     1  0   -   - - 31325 -      ?          0:42 gedit
0 S  1000     -     -  0  80   0 -     - poll_s -          0:41 -
1 S  1000     -     -  0  80   0 -     - poll_s -          0:00 -
1 S  1000     -     -  0  80   0 -     - poll_s -          0:00 -
```

**EDIT:**

```
PC@PCuser:~$ ps -T -l [PID]

F S   UID   PID  SPID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  TTY        TIME CMD
0 S  1000 10070 10070     1  0  80   0 - 31325 poll_s ?          0:42 gedit
1 S  1000 10070 10073     1  0  80   0 - 31325 poll_s ?          0:00 gedit
1 S  1000 10070 10074     1  0  80   0 - 31325 poll_s ?          0:00 gedit
```

Comment: I prefer `ps -T -l [PID]`

Comment: Yes you are correct. It will give some more information. I will update my answer

Comment: What is the priority range? Higher number means higher priority?

Answer (score 2):

$ **ps -T -l [PID]**
can give me more information, but it can't provide the thread name on my system.
I combine this result and 
**(gdb) info thread**
to get more details.

Answer (score 1):

Or, `top -H` (or `top` followed by hitting the `H` key) for interactive view.

However cf. https://superuser.com/questions/286752/unix-ps-l-priority

Answer (score 1):

**ps -T -l -p [PID]**
This command gives me the thread priority info with the thread names